# Find all complex numbers $z$ such as $z$ and $2/z$ have both real and imaginary part integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, solution-verification, integers

I am really struggling to solve this one. I feel like I am missing the key part of the solution, so I would like to see how it's done.

Find all complex numbers $z=x+yi$ such as $z$ and $2z^{-1}$ have both real and imaginary part integers

This is what I thought:
$$2z^{-1} =\frac{2}{z} = \frac{2}{x+yi}= \frac{2}{x+yi}\cdot \frac{x-yi}{x-yi} = \frac{2x-2yi}{x^2+y^2}.$$

In order to $2z^{-1}$ have its imaginary part $\in \mathbb Z$, we should equal $2y$ to $0$
$$2y=0 \Rightarrow y=0$$ $yi=0$ is an integer.

$x$ must also be an integer. We simply assume $x \in \mathbb Z$ (no matter what value $x$ has, as long as it's an integer, we are good).

We do the same for $z$ and find out the same values $yi=0$ and $x \in \mathbb Z$.

Therefore, the set $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb C|x\in \mathbb Z\text{ and }y=0\}$ is the set of all complex numbers whose real and imaginary part are integers.

Comment: This clearly isn't correct since $z=3$ does not have $2z^{-1} = 2/3$ having an integer real part. Your step that "In order to have the imaginary part of $2z^{-1}$ an integer" and setting $y=0$ is not justified. Do you understand what real and imaginary parts are?

Comment: What if $x=3, y=0$? Then $z=3$, $2z^{-1}=2/3$.

Comment: so if $|z|>2$, then $2z^{-1}$ becomes a non integer (which makes its x not an integer). Then z = -1,-2,1,2. correct?

Comment: @FernandoCavendish You're still missing the fact that you set $y=0$ for no reason.

Comment: @FernandoCavendish did you misread the problem as $2z^{-1}$ must be an integer rather than a gaussian integer or did you transcribe it incorrectly? The imaginary part does not need to be zero as it is currently written.

Comment: You need to have $x,y$ both be integers.  But you must *also* have $\frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\frac {-2y}{x^2+y^2}$ both be integers.  You *can* do this by setting $y=0$ but that is not the *only* way to do this.  ... so you two statements 1) "we should equal 2y to 0" and 2) "no matter what value x has, as long as it's an integer, we are good" are both wrong. 1) is wrong because that is not the only way. 2) is wrong because we need more than $x$ being an integer, we need $\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$ be an integer.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that if a complex number $w$ has integral real and complex parts, then $|w|^2$ must be an integer.

Let's start by discussing the possible values of $|z|^2$. Note that $|z|^2$ is an integer, as is $|2z^{-1}|^2 = 4 / |z|^2$. Therefore, we see that $|z|^2$ is an integer factor of 4. This gives us 3 cases for $|z|^2$; it can either be 1, 2, or 4.

Suppose that $|z|^2 = 1$. The only possibilities are $z = \pm 1$ and $z = \pm i$, all of which work.

Now suppose that $|z|^2 = 2$. The only possibilities here are $z = \pm 1 \pm i$ (where the two $\pm$s are independent). A quick check shows that all of these possibilities work.

Finally, the last possibility is that $|z|^2 = 4$. The only possibilities here are $\pm 2$ and $\pm 2i$; again, a quick check shows that all of these work.

These are all the possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

If $z$ and $2/z$ both have real and imaginary parts that are integers, say $z=a+bi$ and $2/z=c+di$, then also
$$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=|z|^2\cdot\left|\frac{2}{z}\right|^2=4.$$
This leaves very few options for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$.

Comment: nice and easy approach

Answer (score 1):

Starting where you left off we have  $$\frac{2x-2yi}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}i$$ which implies that $\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}$ is an integer and so by symmetry $-\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}$ will be an integer as well. Since the numerator grows linearly and the denominators grows quadratically there can only be finitely many such $x$ and $y$ and indeed we see that with $y=0$ and $x=3$ that $x$ has grown too large so $x,y \leq 2$. Now we also see that $2$ divides the numerator, and so the denominator must be a multiple of $2$ as well. This gives us that $x=\pm 1$ or $x=\pm2$. From here we see that the only possible values are $\pm 1 \pm i, \pm 1, \pm i, \pm 2 $ and $\pm 2i$,

Comment: i suppose in the last line of your explanation you mean 2 and not 2x

Comment: @FernandoCavendish you're correct. I'll fix it now.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already determined,

$$2z^{-1} = \frac{2x}{x^2+y^2} + \left(\frac{-2y}{x^2+y^2}\right)i$$

If $x = 0$, then the real part is $0$ and the imaginary part becomes

$$\frac{-2y}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{-2y}{y^2} = \frac{-2}{y}$$

For this to be an integer requires $y \mid -2$, so $y = \pm 1$ or $y = \pm 2$. Similarly, if $y = 0$, we get $x = \pm 1$ or $x = \pm 2$.

If $x \neq 0$ and $y \neq 0$, we get with the real part that

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left\lvert\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert & \ge 1 \\
2\lvert x\rvert & \ge \lvert x\rvert^2 + y^2 \\
1 & \ge \lvert x\rvert^2 - 2\lvert x\rvert + 1 + y^2 \\
1 & \ge (\lvert x\rvert - 1)^2 + y^2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Since $y \neq 0$, then $y^2 \ge 1$, so we must then have $y^2 = 1 \;\to\; y = \pm 1$, and $(\lvert x\rvert - 1)^2 = 0 \;\to\; \lvert x\rvert - 1 = 0 \;\to\; x = \pm 1$. Dealing with the imaginary part in a similar manner leads to the same conditions.

Thus, $(x,y) \in \{(0,\pm 1),(0, \pm 2), (\pm 1, 0), (\pm 2, 0), (\pm 1, \pm 1), (\pm 1, \mp 1)\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $|\frac {2}{z}| < 1$ then either $Re(\frac 2z)$ and $Im(\frac 2z)$ are either zero or non-integer.

But we are not interested in the non-integer cases.

$|z| \le 2$

But if the components of $z$ are integers, there are only a handful complex numbers to work with.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Since we want the real $ \ \left(\frac{2x }{x^2+y^2} \right) \ $ and imaginary $ \ \left(-\frac{2y }{x^2+y^2} \right) \ $ parts of $ \ \frac{2}{z} \ $ to be integers, we can look at the "circles" $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ = \ c \ $ in $ \ \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \ \ . \ $  Because these "curves" have four-fold symmetry, we start by examining the "points" in the first quadrant.  We naturally omit $ \ (0 \ , \ 0) \ $ and observe that we have

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ : } \quad \quad (0 \ , \ 1) \ \ , \ \ (1 \ , \ 0) \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 2 \ \ : } \quad \quad (1 \ , \ 1) \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ : } \quad \quad (0 \ , \ 2) \ \ , \ \ (2 \ , \ 0) \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 5 \ \ : } \quad \quad (2 \ , \ 1) \ \ , \ \ (1 \ , \ 2) \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 8 \ \ : } \quad \quad (2 \ , \ 2)  \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 9 \ \ : } \quad \quad (0 \ , \ 3) \ \ , \ \ (3 \ , \ 0) \ \ ; \ \ $  and so on.

All of these points correspond to the integer real and imaginary parts of $ \ z \ = \ x + yi \ \ . \ $  But the integer-parts requirement for $ \ \frac{2}{z} \ $ means that $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ $ must   first be either $ \ 1 \ $ (making the rational-number parts each   integers) or even.  This eliminates such circles as $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 5 \ \ , \ \ x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 9 \ \ , \ $ etc.  Further, $ \ x^2 + y^2 \ $ can only be even if both $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ have the same parity.  So the next permissible circles have $ \ c \ = \ 10 \ , \ 16 \ , \ 18 \ , \ 20 \ , \ 26 \ , \ 32 \ , \ \ldots \ \ . $

But as we take larger circles, such as $  \ x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 8 \ \ , \ $ we can no longer guarantee that $ \ x \ $ or $ \ y \ $ are *integer multiples* of $ \ (  x^2 + y^2 )/2 \ $ when the rational numbers in the real and imaginary parts of $ \ \frac{2}{z} \ $ are "reduced to lowest terms".  (For $ \ c \ = \ 8 \ \ , \ $ we have $ \ \frac24 \ \ ; \ $ for $ \ c \ = \ 10 \ \ , \ $ either $ \ \frac15 \ $ or $ \ \frac35 \ \ ; \ $ for $ \ c \ = \ 16 \ \ , \   \ \frac12 \ \ ; \ $ and so on.)

We find then that we are limited to the circles and parts (applying the four-fold symmetry)

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 1 \ \ : } \quad \quad (0 \ , \ \pm 1) \ \ , \ \ (\pm 1 \ , \ 0) \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 2 \ \ : } \quad \quad (\pm 1 \ , \ \pm 1) \ \ \ , \ \ (\pm 1 \ , \ \mp 1) \ \ ; $

$ \mathbf{x^2 + y^2 \ = \ 4 \ \ : } \quad \quad (0 \ , \ \pm 2) \ \ , \ \ (\pm 2 \ , \ 0) \ \ . $